# proof regarding isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am working on a graph theory proof but facing problems regarding how to approach to prove it

Consider the following statement: *Given a set of n graphs, {G1, G2, · · · , Gn}, some of the pair of graphs are isomorphic, yet some pair are not. There will be even number of these graphs which are isomorphic to an odd number of graphs. Prove or disprove the statement.*

As for what I can figure out, if the even number of graphs are isomorphic to the odd ones, then vice versa will also be true, disproving the statement. But we are not sure if that would be the only thing.

Pardon if any mistakes made. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement "there will be even number of these graphs which are isomorphic to an odd number of graphs" is quite confusing. What do you mean? That there will be a collection $A$ with an even number of graphs, all of which are isomorphic to an odd number of graphs? Or that if $A$ is the collection of *all* graphs which are isomorphic to an odd number of graphs then $A$ has an even number of elements? Or that there are collections $A$ and $B$ of graphs, with $\#A$ even and $\#B$ odd, all of which are isomorphic?

Comment: Also, if $G_1$ were isomorphic to $G_2,G_3$, then $G_1$ is isomorphic to and even number of other graphs ($G_2$ and $G_3$) but also to an even number (only $G_2$). Actually, should we count that a graph is always isomorphic to itself, in which case any graph will always be isomorphic to an odd number of graphs?

Comment: I am also confused with the problem statement.

Comment: Great. Here's a nice answer then: Take the empty collection of graphs: $\varnothing$. Then $\varnothing$ has 0 elements, which is even. Also, the following statement is vacuously true: "*for every element $H$ of $\varnothing$, the number of graphs among the $G_i$ which are isomorphic to $H$ is odd*". So with this (IMO valid) interpretation of the question, the statement is true, and the proof is above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph $G$ whose vertices are the graph $G_1, G_2, ..., G_n$ with two vertices adjacent if and only if they are isomorphic.  The degree of a vertex is the number of graphs (other than itself) to which the vertex is isomorphic.  By the handshaking lemma, there are an even number of vertices of odd degree.

The statement as given is false, since it overlooks the fact that each graph is isomorphic to itself.